# How can I run ANY java class file graphically? (Linux Mint/Dolphin)

Tags: linux-mint, java, dolphin

When trying to run a .class file, Dolphin will ask me to choose an application to open/run it. However, using the `java` command doesn't remove the `.class` extension from the file, so it can't run. Is there any way to have the file extension removed so that the file will run correctly?

Edit: I've also tried commands like `java ${1%.class}` to no avail.

Comment: Do you have the command to run this `.class` in konsole? Usually you need to define a classpath either via the environment or with the `-classpath` switch. I think it might be easier working with a `jar`

Comment: Working with a jar file is a lot easier, actually. I've decided to take that route; for future reference though, is there any way to format the command given to Dolphin for applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom handler with a bash script:

create file `/usr/local/bin/myhandler.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $1
```

add executable flags `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/myhandler.sh`

In dolphin > right click file > open with > (last entry not sure how it's called in english "own file, not in list") > insert `/usr/local/bin/myhandler.sh` enable all three checkboxes "execute in terminal", second "keep open after execution" and last one "default handler for all files"

Back to the `myhandler.sh`script:

`$1` is the var keeping the full path to that file clicked in dolphin, you may want to adjust the bash script to something like

```
java -classpath /foo/bar $1
```